# Is it posible to open a window then close the window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am not sure how to get by this one. I am using openId with the dotnetopenauth library.

I have some predefined provider that when clicked does a jquery post to the server and does a request to the provider.

I get the url back from provider and I do window.open(....) and open it as a new window with a predefined height and width.

Now they log in and do all that great stuff. Now the provider sends me their information to a controller method that I specified.

Now after I authenticate them I want to go to a new page. However I want to the page to open in the main window and no the window that I opened with window.open(). I want that closed and gone.

I can't get it to work. It will just start using that window.open() window to load all the pages in and I don't want that.

So I no clue what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a complicated piece of work to get right, to be sure.

A couple of good examples are:

- [NerdDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) ([source](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/))
- [DotNetOpenAuth ASP.NET MVC 2 project template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef)

Comment: ya I been looking at nerddinner but I finding confusing how they did it. They also are using an order version and it seems like a few things have changed. I will look at the templates. How do I use the template. I installed it but I am not sure how to actually use it.

Comment: the template seem just as confusing I can't even get the db to create. It keeps telling me that the database does not exist. I tried to create a shell database in the app.config but that did not work either.

Comment: Hmm... try giving Everyone Full Access to your **local** App_Data directory before visiting setup.aspx.  That helps me get the db created sometimes. Then of course figure out how much access to leave in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep a reference to the first window around:

```
var oauthWindow =  window.open(....);
```

later:

```
oauthWindow.close();
```

Comment: Well that was what I was doing for if they canceled since it went back to the login page and I closed that window so they never saw it reload in the secondary window. However once the provider tell me they are authenticated I want to redirect them into their account. So it would load up their account in secondary window while the main window is still on the login page. So if I close the secondary window they are looking at the main login page. So I need to some how transfer the windows or something.

Comment: also probably be better if pages were not redirect constantly it should try to be a smooth transition. I am beginning to think I can't do this. Maybe if I had full control of what was happening in both window.s